# Implementing split function in haskell [Homework]

Tags: haskell

I need to implement a split function in haskell where user gives the as a example input

```
splitx [1,2,3,4,5,6] 3
```

**should output** -> `[1,2,3]`

```
splitx::[Int]->Int->[Int]
splitx [] 0 = []
splitx (x:xs) n = x: splitx xs (n-1)
```

i wrote the following function but it gives a error

```
Non-exhaustive patterns in function Main.splitx
```

just tell me where am i wrong ?

Comment: does you function return the first n elements? is that a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the first n elements:

you have no pattern match for input where n=0 and list is not empty:

```
splitx _ 0 = []
```

Note: specify the type to be generic so it works not only with Ints:

```
splitx :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
```

Comment: yet its returns be the full list :-o

Comment: While your solution is correct, the explanation is not! The only missing pattern is `splitx [] n` where n is not equal to zero. The pattern `splitx _ 0` is matched by `splitx (x:xs) n`.

Comment: You are right. What I wanted to say is that it's matched but shouldn't be, because you want to terminate at that point.

Comment: @Rotsor  @yi_H thanks for the answers . my problem is always i only consider about the main pattern matching thiggy :-s

Answer (score 2):

What should `splitx [] n` be? And how does the computer know that?

Comment: good point.. well, with the current code it is undefined, which matches the specification :)

Answer (score 1):

The error (actually warning, i believe) that you are receiving is complaining that the pattern matches (on the left side of the =) are not exhaustive. You need to add an extra case for the situation where you get `[]` and `n` as arguments.

Comment: By following this suggestion one will get a specialisation of `const` :)

Comment: Derp, I was going on 36 hours without sleep when I wrote my original answer. I've corrected my answer by removing my code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Now that your original question is answered, do you have to use recursion and pattern matching for your homework? If not, you'll notice that `splitx` is a lot like `take` with reversed arguments:

```
GOA> let splitx = flip take
GOA> splitx [1,2,3,4,5,6] 3
[1,2,3]
GOA> splitx [1,2,3,4,5,6] 0
[]
GOA> splitx [] 3
[]
GOA> splitx "abcde" 3
"abc"
```